# how to add dynamically generated pdf file to zipfile Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-pdfkit, python-zipfile

```
z = zipfile.ZipFile("zipfile.zip", "w")
z.write(filename)
```

It takes string as an argument that is actually path of that file to be add to the zip.
But I want to add dynamically generated file.

Answer (score 1):

yes, if you have a buffer you want to dump in your zip file, you can use `writestr` so you avoid creating a temp file:

```
z.writestr(filename,my_buffer)
```

`my_buffer` maybe a `str` (string) or `bytes`

Comment: Like How ? generated pdf file is in the form of HttpResponse and also in form of object of pdfkit.

Comment: `response.read()` gives you `json` I suppose, and you can `json.loads()` it to convert to a dict. The question was unclear about that. It's technically answered. You may want to edit it to provide an example / snippet of what the response returns. I don't mind looking further into it.

Comment: Thanks. But It is showing error while reading response data                          ` 'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'read' ` . Still facing on it.